Angular material 18.2 table expand row with same column as parent and also first and last column should be sticky
I need table expand row with same column as parent and also first and last column should be sticky in angular material project.

Multiple child row open as per parent column width and also first and last column need sticky.

Please guide me for this. how can i achieve on angular material 18.2 project?
